# how to just the a tag with wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I made html file to make web page with WordPress and VS code editor.
I exchange from html file to PHP file.
I wanna make web site like blog page and price chart page and more.
But I don't know how to jump the link with a tag from `front-page.php` to blog list page and news list page.
I made blog list page with  `category.php` and news list page with `archive-news.php`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question you need to create a template https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/  for Listing and Archive page in WordPress and link them using `get_site_url( )`
function

Comment: Please ask to edit the question for clarity first in a comment beneath it, vote on it how helpful it is and ask any clarification questions if you don't understand fully the question before posting an answer. Some questions never reach an answerable state.